# Sending message with nodeMailer

Tags: javascript, express, nodemailer, mern

I want to reset password with nodeMailer.

Here's my post route:
/routes/api/auth.js

```
router.post('/user', (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body

  User.findOne({ email })
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User does not exist' });

      jwt.sign(
        { id: user.id },
        config.get('jwtSecret'),
        { expiresIn: 3600 },
        (err, token) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          res.json({
            token,
            user: {
              id: user.id,
              name: user.name,
              email: user.email
            }
          });
          const url = getPasswordResetURL(user, token);
          console.log(url);
          transporter.sendMail(resetPasswordTemplate(user, url), (err, info) => {
          })
        }
      )
    })
});
```

and my functions:
/modules/mailModule.js

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const config = require('config');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: config.get('email'),
    pass: config.get('password')
  }
})
const getPasswordResetURL = (user, token) =>
  `http://localhost:3000/password/reset/${user._id}/${token}`

const resetPasswordTemplate = (user, url) => {
  const from = config.get('email')
  const to = user.email
  const subject = "Password Reset"
  const html = `
  <p>Hey ${user.name || user.email},</p>
  <p>We heard that you lost your password. Sorry about that!</p>
  <p>But don’t worry! You can use the following link to reset your password:</p>
  <a href=${url}>${url}</a>
  <p>If you don’t use this link within 1 hour, it will expire.</p>
  `
  return { from, to, subject, html }
}    
module.exports = { transporter, getPasswordResetURL, resetPasswordTemplate }
```

and /config/default.json(ofcourse I deleted personal data for this post)

```
{
  "mongoURI": "atlasClusterLink",
  "jwtSecret": "jwtPassword",
  "email": "myEmail@gmail.com",
  "password": "myPassword"
}
```

In first file I've done

> console.log(url)

to check if changing password with url works and it works, but I can't send this. I don't get any message. First time I did this I get message from google no-reply mail(critical security alert)  that someone(me) tried to login on my account from non-google aplication.
I just want to send this url on some mail addresses and it would be great if I could do this with no-reply mail address. 
Later also I plan to use dotenv in place of config, but it will be realized later.